# How to store spark streaming dataframe to Mysql table.?

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

am trying to read data from Azure event hub and store this dataframe to Mysql table in spark streaming mode.

below is the my pyspark code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter

try:
    session = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("dataingestion").config("")
    spark = session.getOrCreate()
    print("Successfully build spark session : ")
except:
    print("Fail to build spark session : ")
    raise Exception

startoffset = "@latest"
positionKey1 = {
  "ehName": eventhubName,
  "partitionId": 0
}
endTime = dt.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
eventPosition1 = {
  "offset": startoffset,    
  "seqNo": 0,              
  "enqueuedTime": endTime,   
  "isInclusive": True
}
positionMap = {
  json.dumps(positionKey1) : eventPosition1
}
 
# Place the map into the main Event Hub config dictionary
ehreadConf = {}
ehreadConf["eventhubs.startingPositions"] = json.dumps(positionMap)
 
ehreadConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = event_hub_sas_key
ehreadConf['eventhubs.consumerGroup'] = "$Default"
ehreadConf['eventhubs.maxEventsPerTrigger'] = 5000

try:
    inputStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehreadConf).load()
    print("Successfully connected the event hub : ")
    print("Check streaming is started or not : ", inputStream.isStreaming)
    print("Schema of inputStream : ", inputStream.printSchema())
except Exception:
    print("Fail to connect with Azure event hub : ")
    raise Exception
inputStream = inputStream.withColumn("body", inputStream["body"].cast("string"))



db_target_properties = {"user": username, "password": password, "driver": driver}
 
def foreach_batch_function(sparkDf,epoach_id):
    sparkDf.write.option("batchsize","5000").jdbc(url=url, table="demo",properties=db_target_properties, mode="append")
    pass
 
 
query = sparkDf.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").option("truncate", 'false').option(
    "checkpointLocation", "dbfs:/FileStore/lambda-StreamJob/AzureSql/checkpoint").trigger(processingTime='8 seconds').foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
 
query.awaitTermination()


spark.stop()
```

but am unable to store this spark dataframe into mysql table.
am getting an error like data source jdbc dose not support spark streaming.

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.start.
> : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source jdbc does not support streamed writing>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error notes, support for writing from a stream to a JDBC sink is not present in Spark Yet (I guess).
Instead of writing stream directly into mysq, you can do a forEachBatch in the streamDf and do the `write.jdbc` operation.

```
server_name = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"
database_name = "eventhub"
jdbcurl = server_name + "/" + database_name
table_name = "stream_cdr_data"
db_properties = {"user":""user"", "password":"data@123"}

def write_to_mysql(df, epoch_id):
    dfwriter = df.write.mode("append") 
    dfwriter.jdbc(url=jdbcurl, table=table_name, properties=db_properties) # if this is not working use below
    #df.write.jdbc(url=jdbcurl, table=table_name, properties=db_properties, mode="append")
    pass

query = sparkDf.writeStream.outputMode("append").foreachBatch(write_to_mysql).start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

For below Issue (OP asked in below comment section)

`request/expected seqNo xxxx is less than the received seqNo xxxx. The earliest seqNo is yyyy and the last seqNo is yyyy`

Take a look at the [FAQ](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/FAQ.md)  !!!!!

Comment: ```Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o425.awaitTermination.
: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: 
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o466.jdbc.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view 'stream_job_data' already exists. SaveMode: ErrorIfExists```

Comment: Hi Badusha Thank you for your Answer, i have tried this way but it only insert first micro batch of records, Means Suppose i have 50000 records in event hub then it only store the first micro batch of 1000 records into mysql. And after then i will get the above error.

Comment: @akshay, Are you using mode `append`. Pleas see changes in above code

Comment: Let me which solution worked properly on you

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works for streaming data.

Comment: Above code is work but when am writing any transformation query on it and try to store this streaming data into mysql table am getting sequence number issue.

Comment: ```org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 823, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalStateException: In partition 0 of akshay-ntt-stream-deom-1, with consumer group $Default, request seqNo 4001 is less than the received seqNo 4002. The earliest seqNo is 0 and the last seqNo is 49999```

Comment: @akshay,I can see that youre using checkpoint in your streaming, pleas make sure that ur using full path best practice is to use hdfs path bcz in reality spak/hadoop jobs run in different node / machines.

Comment: I tried this code on Azure databricks but getting above error. below is the my code as you suggest.

Comment: @akshay, pleas change your checkpoint location to hdfs,

Comment: `def foreach_batch_function(sparkDf,epoach_id):
    sparkDf.write.jdbc(url=url, table="stream_demo_1_databricks",
                             properties=db_target_properties, mode="append")
    pass

query = sparkDf.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").option("truncate", 'false').option(
    "checkpointLocation", "/dbfs/FileStore/Today-Stream-demo-1/AzureSql/checkpoint").trigger(processingTime='8 seconds').foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()

query.awaitTermination() `

Comment: above code is working correctly ..?

Comment: Yes the above code is working, But am facing the issue while reading the records from the Event hub. Every time it will only create the micro batch of 1000K records. and it takes to much time to process the whole 1lakh records. Please see the above updated code.

Comment: @akshay, I know this too late, but this is for other folks. (For Seq Number issue i have updated the answer )