# Why Azure Event hub show outgoing messages as double than the incomming messages

Tags: python, azure, pyspark

Hi all I have 50K records in my Event hub but when am reading this records from event hub using pyspark the the outgoing messages count gets double. Why this is shown me as ougoing messages count as double than incomming messages.

I have attached below screent shot of Event hub message processing.
[Azure Event hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt1Bo.jpg)

Comment: @Jesse Squire i have attach the screent shot of my Azure Event hub metricks, i have three consumer group including default

Comment: @badhusha muhammed do you know about this issue

Comment: @Jesse Squire I have my code in the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451637/how-to-store-spark-streaming-dataframe-to-mysql-table/70453325?noredirect=1#comment124637665_70453325

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.